# Html code works in firefox,safari,chrome but not in ie why

Tags: iframe, cross-browser, google-sheets

```
 <html>
  <body>    
   <iframe width='500' height='500' frameborder='0' src='https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0ApILEVmEy4YHdGRTdGZNTWd1cmc2c0RPN0dtSnZGWHc&hl=en'>
   </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

This Code dispays spreadsheet in some bowsers.In all bowsers it shows spreadsheets but ie it shows login page

Comment: *sarcasm* Because IE always tries to trouble web developers with individual and mostly stupid behavior! */sarcasm* Sorry ;)

Comment: Do you actually need to be logged in to view the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Alex But Why did it show in Firefox and chrome.

Comment: Previously you were logged in in those browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried too many things at once, so I missed what actually fixed it. Accepting 3rd party cookies worked.

[image]

Comment: In all bowsers it shows spreadsheets but ie it shows login page.

Comment: @Brad No, not allowing 3rd party cookies

Comment: @ugesh, always try the simple stuff first, right? Add that space.

Comment: @Brad Added space but no use.

Comment: @ugesh, sorry for the red herring. I made too many changes at once and missed what actually fixed it.

Comment: @Brad Thank you, but i had a small doubt.I am developing a program on this. How can i say all the users to accept forcibly to change their privacy settings.

Comment: @ugesh, perhaps you can suggest they use a different browser, but definitely put this in your FAQ and put a `DIV` on the page that tells the users about this (use CSS/JavaScript to show the `DIV` only in IE). I think you will find setting the cookie policy all the way down necessary and adding the website to "safe sites" may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It could be security settings since that link is encrypted via https and (perhaps) your parent page is not. IE usually throws warnings when you use secure/insecure items in the same page.